# problem with ajax url address .its not working

Tags: php, ajax

I want to compare my field value to mysql field with ajax.

this is my ajax cod:

```
$("#checkCodeButton").click(function() {

    var enteredCodeField = $("#order-discount").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'check.php',
        data: {
            enteredCode: enteredCodeField
        },
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    })
});
```

and this is my code in check.php

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "animating-wp");


date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran');
$days = 0;
$hours = 0;
$discountPercent = 0;

if (isset($_POST['enteredCode']) && !empty($_POST['enteredCode'])) {

    $SelectDiscountQuery = "SELECT  *  FROM discounts   WHERE  discount_code = ' " . $_POST['enteredCode'] . " ' ";

    $discountResult = mysqli_query($link, $SelectDiscountQuery);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($discountResult) > 0){
        echo "blah blah";
    } else {
        echo "blah";
    }
}
```

but I dont know why when I'm clicking on the button it doesn't work?
( also I run this in wordpress them and linked jquery in script>
thanks

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: You have extra spaces in your query, so `discount_code = ' " . $_POST['enteredCode'] . " ' ";` will check for `' enteredCode '` exactly. Remove the extra spaces, or use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to eliminate spacing/quoting confusion as well as prevent Sql injection.